# Неперезаписываемый, но изменяемый экземпляр объекта

Tags: java, c++, объекты, const

Возникла необходимость создать экземпляр объекта (например `string`), так, чтобы он удовлетворял следующим условиям:

1. Его **нельзя** было бы перезаписать - т.е.

   //объявление и определение экземпляра string a (данный экземпляр должен удовлетворять данным условиям)

   //объявление и определение какого-то другого экземпляра string b

   a = b; //невозможно
2. Экземпляр можно изменять через его методы

Вопрос: каким образом объявить такой экземпляр?

P.S. Я пришел из Java, где `final ArrayList<Integer> a` означает, лишь то, что невозможно перезаписать `a` другим `ArrayList`, но однако в данный список мы можем добавлять элементы и удалять их. В C++ же, если объект помечен как `const` мы не можем его никак изменять

**UPD**

Проблема заключается в следующем: у меня есть класс `Scene` (упрощенно, его можно представить так):

```
class Scene {
private:
    std::vector<GameObject*> instances;
public:
    const GameObject& getInstance(unsigned int id);
    void destroyInstance(unsigned int id);
}
```

В классе `GameObject` имеются методы, которые позволяют изменять его состояние. При этом `getInstance()` должен возвращать указ./ссылку на `GameObject`, при этом, я бы не хотел, чтобы можно было перезаписывать `GameObject` находящийся по возвращенному ссылке/указ., однако при этом, я хотел бы, чтобы можно было вызывать методы `GameObject` изменяющие его состояние. Это можно сделать только через запрет операторов?

Comment: Тут на самом деле вылезает некоторое логическое противоречие. Дело в том, что все поля объекта могут быть перезаписаны через любой из методов, изменяющих его состояние, и вызов такого метода не будет чем-то отличаться от вызова оператора =, однако эффекта "как в javа" никогда не будет. Оператор = имеет смысл запрещать, если не нужен метод, изменяющий сразу все поля (особенно потому что operator = может неявно генерироваться компилятором приводя к нежелательным эффектам).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну в С++ (раз уж вы указали этот тэг) [это просто](https://ideone.com/W5gOzt). Запретить конструкторы копирования/перемещения, и присвоение, и все.

```
Type(const Type&)            = delete;
Type& operator=(const Type&) = delete;
```

(в старом C++ сделать их `private` и без тела).

Имеющийся же класс - его семантика полностью определена. Остается его, скажем, наследовать или прятать в обертку, и уже его/ее запрещать.

Comment: Код на по ссылке не компилируется. А если класс уже существует (`string`, `vector`) - что делать?

Comment: Правильно! Я показал именно это - что он не компилируется!

Comment: А если класс уже существует - то его семантика уже определена, в частности, что он может копироваться...

Comment: @wcobalt В С++ классы можно использовать подобно базовым типам в java, тогда аналогом final будет `const` квалификатор, и подобно объектам в java (когда переменные содержат ссылку на объект) - тогда присваивание другого объекта будет не ребиндить ссылку, как в java, а вызывать метод `operator =`. Приведенный в этом ответе способ запрещения присваивания будет действовать как запрещение присваивания для базового типа в java (если бы такое было возможно), а не как аналог `final`.

Comment: @Harry я обновил вопрос

Comment: Гм. В вашем описании для меня непонятным остается "перезаписывать"... Вам, случайно, не [синглтон](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29) нужен?

Comment: @Harry я имел ввиду что-то вроде `GameObject a = new ....; GameObject b = new...; a = b;` Честно говоря, не понимаю куда можно тут прикрутить синглтон

Comment: @Harry я просто не хотел бы, чтобы было возможно следующее: я вернул адрес по которому лежит `GameObject` (к примеру 1150). Затем вызывающий код заменил этот `GameObject` на другой, но все по тому же адресу. (Возможно это бред, извините, я плох в C++)

Comment: Через `new` выделяется объекты в куче, и возвращаются указатели, т.е. `GameObject * a = new...`, и вот тут вы уже никак не сможете запретить присваивания `a = b`. Простите, но у меня ощущение, что вы просто натягиваете костюм Java на манекен C++... Ощущение такое, что ваша проблема в не совсем правильном - с точки зрения С++ - дизайне.

Comment: @Harry возможно. После Java сложновато начать думать в терминах C++.

Comment: "Затем вызывающий код заменил этот GameObject на другой, но все по тому же адресу" - так это как раз и есть копирование...

Comment: @Harry какую бы вы предпочли архитектуру для класса `Scene`?

Comment: Да я вообще не очень понимаю, чем вам этот способ не нравится... тРазве сто возвращать два варианта - `const GameObject& getInstance(unsigned int id) const` и `GameObject& getInstance(unsigned int id)`. На случай константной сцены :)

Answer (score 2):

Тут надо пояснить, что семантика присваивания и ссылок в Java и С++ радикально различается. В выражении `final ArrayList<Integer> a` `a` является ссылочным типом и `final` запрещает  привязку ссылки к другому объекту. В С++ же ссылочные типы в принципе нельзя заставить ссылаться на другой объект (т.е. они всегда являются `final` с точки зрения Java), однако вызов оператора = при присваивании объекта является как раз ни чем иным как изменением объекта через его метод, а не привязкой ссылки к другому объекту.

```
::std::string obj{}; // объект
::std::string & str{obj}; // ссылка на объект
::std::string other{"other"};
str = other; // str продолжает ссылаться на тот же самый объект, он был модифицирован
str.operator =(other); // присваивание аналогично вызову метода, изменяющего объект
```

Кроме того, в С++ объекты могут использоваться без ссылки, в таком случае `const` квалификатор работает аналогично `final` для базовых типов в Java.

```
final int i=10;
i = 3; // error

::std::string const str{};
str = ::std::string{"other"}; // error
```

Comment: я обновил вопрос

Comment: @wcobalt Перезаписать объект через возвращаемую ссылку "как в java" в С++ нельзя в любом случае. Через ссылку объект можно только модифицировать, при этом ссылка всегда будет продолжать ссылаться на тот же самый объект. Еще стоит отметить что `GameObject*` вообще-то является указателем на объект, чему в java опять же нет прямого аналога.

Comment: вы имеете в виду, следующее: предположим есть ссылка указывающая на 101 ячейку памяти, в ней хранится число `9` (`int`) например. Я не могу заменить `9` на `10`? Или вы имеете ввиду, что адрес нельзя изменить (Это я знаю)?

Comment: @wcobalt Если объект изменяемый, то можете. В своем примере вы возвращаете ссылку на неизменяемый объект `const GameObject&` соответственно модифицировать его вызвав `operator =` или другой модифицирующий метод не получится. А если возвращать ссылку на изменяемый объект `GameObject&`, то его можно будет модифицировать вызвав `operator =` или другой модифицирующий метод, причем запрет вызова метода `operator =` (как это описано в соседнем ответе) не будет защищать от перезаписи.

Comment: @wcobalt В С++ нельзя заменить объект один на другой. Можно модифицировать все его поля, сделав их такими же, как в другом объекте (с вызовом оператора = или без него), но сам объект останется тем же самым.  А операция, аналогичная присваиванию объектов в java, в С++ невозможна.

Answer (score 2):

В C++ у экземпляров классов отсутствует идентичность, так что вы не можете в общем случае определить был ли объект перезаписан или мутирован. Если в Java вы можете сравнить два значения оператором == и определить, являются ли они одним и тем же объектом, в C++ оператор == либо перегружен и сравнивает по значению, либо не перегружен и просто отсутствует.

Еще можно сказать так: оператор присваивания - это такой же мутирующий метод, как и остальные методы.

Так что то, что вы пытаетесь сделать, просто лишено смысла.

---

Возможно, вам на самом деле нужно ограничить число способов изменения объекта. В таком случае вам нужно написать класс-обертку. Замечу, что в отличии от Java в C++ классы без виртуальных членов бесплатны: они не требуют лишней памяти кроме памяти под свои члены, а вызовы методов инлайнятся оптимизатором по возможности.

Например, можно сделать вот так:

```
class myvector {
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    std::vector<int> const & value() {
        return v;
    }

    void push_back(int x) {
        v.push_back(x);
    }

    myvector(const myvector&) = delete;
    void operator=(const myvector&) = delete;
}
```

Comment: *то, что вы пытаетесь сделать, просто лишено смысла* Ну почему? Например (надуманно, конечно...), класс, работающий с ресурсом - типа файла через `FILE*` - который в C++ сам пор себе копируется, но вы не хотите его позволить копировать, как, например, потоки. Но при этом в нем есть нормальное изменяемое состояние...

Comment: @Harry автор хочет сделать так не со своим классом, а с чужим. И это как раз лишено смысла.

Comment: А, в этом смысле - да, согласен с вами.

Comment: Что-то вас не туда понесло... В C++ у экземпляров классов идентичность очень даже присутствует. А присваивание применительно к ссылочным типам имеет другую семантику и работает как вызов метода вместо переназначения ссылки.

Comment: @VTT э-э-э, что такое "ссылочный тип" в C++?

Comment: `::std::string & str{obj}; // ссылка на объект`, с точки зрения java они всегда являются final

Comment: @VTT что же до идентичности - найдите, пожалуйста, отличие между `&a` и `&a` до и после присваивания `a = ""s`

Comment: @PavelMayorov А какой результат вы ожидаете? В таком примере до и после имеется единственный объект `a`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я обновил вопрос